Make keyboard push widget flutter
How do I get my widget to move up when the keyboard appears:
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: Sizes.twenty),
          Text(
            appInfo.appName,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headlineMedium!
                .copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: Sizes.forty),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text(
              tr(context)
                  .enterVerificationCodeTitle
                  .toUpperCase(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: Sizes.twenty,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text(
              tr(context)
                  .enterVerificationCodeBody(widget.phoneNumber),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: Sizes.sixteen),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: Sizes.ten),
            child: Pinput(
              defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
              focusedPinTheme: focusedPinTheme,
              length: 6,
              onTap: () {
                if (widget.error != null) {
                  controller.text = "";
                }
              },
              onSubmitted: widget.verifyCode,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              controller: controller,
              cursor: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 9),
                    width: 22,
                    height: 1,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              androidSmsAutofillMethod:
                  AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.none,
              pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.none,
              pinputAutovalidateMode:
                  PinputAutovalidateMode.disabled,
              validator: (pin) {
                if (widget.error == null &&
                    pin != null &&
                    pin.length == 6) {
                  widget.verifyCode(pin);
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: Sizes.twentyHeight),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: CustomElevatedButton(
              title: tr(context).validate.toUpperCase(),
              backgroundColor: null,
              foregroundColor: null,
              onPressed: () {
                focusNode.unfocus();
                formKey.currentState!.validate();
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: Sizes.twentyHeight),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: widget.delayBeforeNewCode > 0
                ? null
                : widget.resendCode,
            child: Text(
              widget.delayBeforeNewCode > 0
                  ? tr(context).delayHint(
                      widget.delayBeforeNewCode.toString())
                  : tr(context).resendCode,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ),
          if (widget.error != null)
            ErrorText(
              message: widget.error?.getErrorText(context, null),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

I have played with padding and mediaQuery without success.

Set this on scaffold:
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true
)


The default of that property is already true.
